# How to protect user to take session cookie from one browser and paste it in other for login?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, session-cookies

Using node.js/express I would like to create social site. For this I'm maintaining session using express-session in redis and in a cookie at client site. But if I copy that cookie and paste it in different browser it logs me in, how to protect it?
And what are other ways to maintain session and good practices for it?